# can I make multiple transactional updates with CI and if one fails rollback them all?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making an update for multiple entries with CodeIgniter, my doubt is if I am using the transaction correctly... right now I have this

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $b){
    try{
       $querystring = "somemysql to update... pure mysql";  
       $query = $this->db->query($querystring);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
}
$this->db->trans_commit();
```

At the moment, i havent get any error... and seems to be working fine, what I dont know is this:

If im for the update 4/100 lets say, will this rollback the #4 only? or the #1,#2,#3 as well?

Any idea? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have written this, if there is an exception on 4; 1,2,3 will be rolled back..

**BUT** it will continue on with 5+, presumably this is not what you want!

I also assume `trans_rollback()` ends the transaction so the next queries will be run outside of the transaction and won't be rolled back if another exception occurs. You may even get an uncaught exception on `trans_commit()` or another attempted `trans_rollback()`.

I am guessing what you want is:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
try{
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $b){
    $querystring = "somemysql to update... pure mysql"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($querystring);
  }
  $this->db->trans_commit();
}
catch(Exception $e){
  $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
```

Comment: thank you, what is the difference between this method and use a break; when the transaction fails? which one is more efficient?

Comment: This will break out of the try (and the contained loop) as soon as any exception occurs in the try (bypassing any further queries planned and the commit); the exception is then caught in the catch (outside the try and loop) and the rollback occurs. Is that what you meant?